# Error response from daemon: Container f88566c370dd is not running

Tags: docker, chef-infra, boot2docker, chef-recipe

I am observing the below error while I execute the below command.

> cmd used-  `docker exec -it f88566c370dd /bin/bash`
> error observed- `Error response from daemon: Container f88566c370dd is not running`

I am trying to execute a Chef recipe from a VM to pull an image and run three CentOS containers.

#### Chef recipe

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: chef-docker
# Recipe:: default    #
# Copyright 2016, SONATA_SOFTWARE    #
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#
docker_service 'default' do
  action [:create, :start]
end

# Pull latest image
docker_image 'centos' do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end

# Run container
docker_container 'first' do
  repo 'centos'
  command 'ls -la /'
  end

  docker_container 'second' do
  repo 'centos'
  command 'ls -la /'
  end

  docker_container 'third' do
  repo 'centos'
  command 'ls -la /'
  end
```

Command used in VM to execute chef recipe

```
chef-client -r recipe[chef-docker::Default]
```

Expected Result: Installation of software such as Java, Python, or tools such as Jenkins and Tomcat in containers.

```
[root@sonatadocker ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                                                 VIRTUAL SIZE
centos              latest              97cad5e16cb6        3 weeks ago                                             196.5 MB

[root@sonatadocker ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
f88566c370dd        centos:latest       "ls -la /"          18 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago                       third
fdc12e9f65a9        centos:latest       "ls -la /"          18 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago                       second
604f0eba7010        centos:latest       "ls -la /"          18 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago                       first
```

Comment: the docker container is not created. Can you update the question with the output of the script you are running ? does `docker ps -a` list your container ?

Comment: @user2599522- Updated the question.

Comment: status: Exited, of course you cant connect

Comment: docker logs f88

Comment: @YOU How to start and Run the containers which are exited manually

Comment: `docker start f8`, if it exited quickly then you should check the logs.

Comment: @YOU I could see nothing functioning after executing below.

[root@sonatadocker ~]# docker logs third
ls: cannot access /;: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access sleep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 10m: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /;: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access sleep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 10m: No such file or directory

Comment: hmm, I only know docker but not chef, and can't understand your use case with ls -la /. In my case, I use offcial jenkins image - https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/, and do those installation like ci stuff inside jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the container up, Docker needs a command to keep running in the foreground.

In your case, the command ***"ls -la /"*** lists the directory contents and exits, which results in exiting the container. Try starting containers with commands which continue to run in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Your containers run only one command and then exit.

```
docker_container 'first' do
  repo 'centos'
  command 'ls -la /'
  end
```

Think of this as spawning a subshell, performing `ls -al /`, and then exiting.

A hack to keep them up and running will be to change the command to:

```
ls -la /; sleep 10m
```

To verify your containers have run the command, you can check the logs of the container with:

```
docker logs third
```

Comment: How can keep them running continuously. ls -la /; sleep 10m will make them down after 10m.

Comment: Above solution didnt work as well.
[root@sonatadocker ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
ba6cbedeb3da        centos:latest       "ls -la /; sleep 10m   About a minute ago   Exited (2) 58 seconds ago                           third

Comment: i got two questions: (1) why do you need a container to be up and running whithout running any commands and (2) whats the logs from the container you tried

Comment: 1- So that I can SSH to the container and build applications into it.
2- As the container is in Exited sate I am not able to fetch the logs.
[root@sonatadocker ~]# docker logs first
ls: cannot access /;: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access sleep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 10m: No such file or directory

Comment: To be more specific-so that we can login and run some commands and configure the container

Comment: there might be something wrong with the image you are using (maybe paths are wrong ?). Also [this](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the command to "/bin/bash" I could see containers in in the up state.

```
docker_service 'default' do
  action [:create, :start]
end
# Pull latest image
docker_image 'centos' do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end
# Run container
docker_container 'first' do
  repo 'centos'
  command '/bin/bash'
  tty true
  action :run
  end
  docker_container 'second' do
  repo 'centos'
  command '/bin/bash'
  tty true
  action :run
  end
```